# Oracle RETURNING from a INSERT .. SELECT

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to insert a row into a table from a SELECT statement (as opposed to VALUES syntax) and use the RETURNING clause to retrieve a column value?

Using the SELECT syntax fails with ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended:

```
DECLARE
    l_id users.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users (id, name)
    SELECT users_seq.nextval, 'foo'
    FROM DUAL
    RETURNING id INTO l_id;
END;
/
```

It works fine with the VALUES syntax of course:

```
DECLARE
    l_id users.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users (id, name)
    VALUES (users_seq.nextval, 'foo')
    RETURNING id INTO l_id;
END;
/
```

Comment: No, it just isn't valid to do that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423 (search for single_table_insert) it is not supported in normal SQL, and I believe not in PL/SQL either.